# How does the mySQL INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY column = VALUE( column ) + 1 work?

Tags: mysql, insert-update

***Please see the Updated section of this question that follows after the initial question.***

I have two tables, one for videos that contains a **id**, **users_id**, **image**,  **pcimagename**, and **video URL** columns; and another for images that contains a **id**, **users_id**, **file_name**, **user_file_name**, and **usage_count** columns.

The primary key of both tables are the **id** columns, which are auto-incrementing, but the two **id** values are not related to each other.  The **images** table also has a unique key on the **file_name** column.  The **usage_count** column has 1 for its default value.

The phpMyAdmin shows the following information about the mySQL database that I'm using:

```
Database server
  Server:           Localhost via UNIX socket
  Server type:      MariaDB
  Server version:   5.5.52-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
  Protocol version: 10
  Server charset:   UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

My goal is that whenever a row is to be deleted from the videos table, I want to first copy the image information from the videos table into the images table, and if the image (specifically the **file_name** column value) doesn't already exist in the **images** table, set the **usage_count** to 1, but, if the image does exist, I want to increment the **usage_count** by 1 and perform an update.  I searched for "mySQL INSERT or UPDATE" and came up with with the **INSERT ... ON DUPLCATE KEY UPDATE** variant, which appears to be what I'm trying to do.

However, I've never used the **INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...** statement before. Looking at the [MySQL INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/) and [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists) pages, I came up with the following; unfortunately, I'm able to connect to my database at this time, so I'm unable to determine if it is correct:

```
INSERT
  INTO `photos`
        ( `users_id`, `file_name`, `user_file_name` )
SELECT `users_id`, `image`, `pcimagename`
FROM `videos`
WHERE `status` = \'Deleted\'
   AND `last_updated_on` <= DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY )
   AND `tracks_id` = 0
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE usage_count = VALUES( usage_count ) + 1;
```

My questions are:

1. Is the syntax correct, specifically:

   1a) Is the placement of the **ON DUPLICATE** phrase correct?

   1b) Do I need to enclose the **SELECT** statement in parenthesizes, I've seen examples which did and others that didn't.
2. Will the **UPDATE usage_count = VALUES( usage_count ) + 1** phrase cause each row inserted into the image table to add 1 to the row's pre-insert usage_count value, or will all of the rows coming from the **SELECT FROM videos** be given the same value?  I didn't see very much about how this part of the **ON DUPLICAT** statement actually worked.  Most examples just assigned a fixed value.

***Update***

While working with the [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=c8efcccea1c4c8f1f1da161f5751e832) that Anina provided, I noticed that running the following **INSERT** statement didn't increment as I expected:

```
After several INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... statements the test 
table contains:

id  val test    action  comment
1   1   2       update  
2   2   2       update  
3   3   1       insert  

Perform another INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... statement,
this time to increment val 1, expecting that the test column should increment to 3.

INSERT INTO test (val ) 
VALUES ( 1 )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test = VALUES( test ) + 1,
                        action = 'update',
                        comment = 'Why isn''t test 3?';

 However ....

 id val test    action  comment
 1  1   2       update  Why isn't test 3?
 2  2   2       update  
 3  3   1       insert
```

The table was created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id      INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY( ID ),
                    val     INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE( val ),
                    test    INT DEFAULT 1,
                    action  VARCHAR( 10 ) DEFAULT 'insert',
                    comment VARCHAR( 30 ) );
```

Thanks

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE photos set usage_count = usage_count + 1;` The manual pages are quite clear [see the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: *Will the `UPDATE usage_count = VALUES( usage_count ) + 1` phrase cause each row inserted into the image table to add 1 to the row's pre-insert `usage_count` value, or will all of the rows coming from the `SELECT FROM videos` be given the same value?* Neither first nor second. Read carefully the Reference Manual about VALUES() function action.

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=82699c5d56ee24771c40495a8f3b0c4b) - investigate.

Comment: Thank you all.  Anina, your fiddle was most helpful concerning my question about how the VALUES() expression in the ON DUPICATE KEY phase worked.

Comment: RiggsFolly,  I didn't bring up the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual page on for the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement because for v5.6, the earliest version of that page in the manual pages, and one past the version of mySQL that I'm using, it didn't answer all of my questions, or if it did, I didn't find it clear enough, so I missed what I asked about in the question posted, here.  Not the manual's fault.  Which is why I asked my question, here.  However, thanks for adding the link for anyone who reads this question and want for information about the clause.

Answer (score 0):

***Answer to the Update***:

In order to make the test column beyond 2, I added the following **UPDATE TRIGGER** after creating the test table, before any inserts on existing rows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_test_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET new.test = old.test + 1;
END;
```

This causes the test column to increment its value in the existing row by 1, rather than the failed insert's test value (1) incremented by 1 (always 2).

See this [dbLink](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=80467d445b4f00b18f4b910474b21215) for an example that shows how this works.

However, because the ON DUPLICATE KEY phrase just converts the **INSERT** to an **UPDATE**, which intern uses the above trigger to correct the test increment.  Actual **UPDATE**s will also call the same trigger when any of the column in an existing row are updated, causing an incorrect test column value.

The mySQL manual says:

```
With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the
row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an
existing row is set to its current values. If you specify the
CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag to the mysql_real_connect() C API function when
connecting to mysqld, the affected-rows value is 1 (not 0) if an existing
row is set to its current values.
```

Is there a way to use the fact that the **affected-rows** value is 2 when the **ON DUPLICARE KEY UPDATE** phrase converts the **INSERT** to an **UPDATE** in the **BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER** or an **AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER** or some other means to determine this happened, rather than when a direct **UPDATE** is made, where the **affected-rows** value is 1?

If so how do I get the **affected-rows** value from within a TRIGGER?

Note: In my code I'm using an **INSERT** from a sub-**SELECT** so multiple rows could be added before returning a value to my program.  Therefore, I'm looking for a Purely-mySQL solution that runs when multiple rows are inserted.

Comment: None of the help you received indicated you needed to add a trigger.  Why have you done so?  All you needed to do was change your update statement to `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE usage_count = usage_count + 1;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion gview, but I'm already using that phrase.  The BEFORE TRIGGER is a work-around needed because the usage_count/test column value stops incrementing past 2.

Comment: If you did look at the link to dbFiddle in the Updated section of my question, you would see that the inserts against the value 1 after it is initially added to the table all have a test value of 2. What I need, as stated in the initial question is for the test value to start at 1, using the default value for that column, then with each INSERT, changed to an UPDAT by the ON DUPLICATE ... phrase, increment by 1, going from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4, etc. This doesn't happen without the BEFORE INSERT trigger.  The dbLink in my answer solves this problem by adding the BEFORE TRIGGER.

Comment: However, simply swopping INSERT to UPDATE due to the ON DUPLICATE ... phrase doesn't fully work because I when I change the value of any of column other than test with an explicit UPDATE statement the trigger fires and usage_count (or test) column's value is incremented. In my project code the column is usage_count. In the dbFiddle example the test column performs the same function.  I need to somehow only call the BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER when the ON DUPLICATE swops from INSERT to UPDATE.